# Circuit for generating a PWM signal of varying high and low voltage values

Tags: operational-amplifier, pwm, circuit-design, potentiometer, function-generator

I have a microcontroller that is generating a PWM signal between 0 and 12V of varying frequency. I'm looking to build some sort of circuit that will take this signal and then attenuate the high and low values of that square wave to be anywhere between 0 and Vmax (12V in this case). The trick here is that the low signal may need to be higher than 0V, so it can't just be a voltage divider on the square wave.

I would guess that this would use some sort of potentiometer or maybe even a variable op amp, but I'm a software guy and don't know what I'm doing. :)

Basically I want to be able to generate high and low voltage values of my choice while still retaining the frequency and duty cycle. Ex. 250mV-500mV, 3V-5V, etc.

Any ideas where to start, or what a circuit for this would look like? Please comment if more information is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a precision clamp might be OK: -

[image]

U1 clamps the maximum level at the value V3 and U2 keeps the minimum level no lower than V5.

Probably best to do a simulation to see how those particular op-amps handle the maximum PWM frequency you are wanting to use - faster devices can of course be chosen.

Comment: Could you explain the difference between the clamped output and the optional buffered output?

Comment: The buffer is there to be able to drive a load resistor without affecting the levels - if you look you will see that there is a 1 kohm resistor (R1) present and this means you cannot put too much load on the unbuffered output without upsetting the signal levels.

Comment: Thank you. This is looking good on a simulation except there are pretty large spikes on the edges that will need to get filtered out. I'm running between 250mV and 500mV. Maybe need a capacitor somewhere?

Comment: Are they "overshoots"? Maybe try a faster op-amp?

Comment: What op-amp did you use in the sim and what frequency is your PWM (just for my reference)?

Comment: I changed them to a LT6221 which reduced the overshot by about 1/2 of what it was. There is still a little bit of overshot, but I am going to keep trying different amps until I find something that is a bit more perfect. I will let you know what that ends up being. I am simulating a 100 Hz wave.

Comment: You could try a 1 or 10 nF capacitor across the unbuffered output to 0V and see if that improves things.

Comment: I ended up putting an RC filter on the end with about 250 ohms and 0.01 uF. This looks good up to 10kHz which will not get exceeded on this particular application.